# How to replace/remove 4(+)-byte characters from a UTF-8 string in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

Because MySQL 5.1 does not support 4 byte UTF-8 sequences, I need to replace/drop the 4 byte sequences in these strings.

I'm looking a clean way to replace these characters.

Apache libraries are replacing the characters with a question-mark is fine for this case, although ASCII equivalent would be nicer, of course.

N.B. The input is from external sources (e-mail names) and upgrading the database is not a solution at this point in time.

Comment: You’re kidding.  MySQL still doesn’t support Unicode in this day and age?  That’s unconscionable.  Pretending that you support Unicode when you can only handle 1-, 2-, or 3- byte UTF-8 sequences is just as big a lie as saying that you support Unicode when you support only 1-byte ASCII sequences.  Either you support any legal Unicode code point, or you don’t support Unicode. It’s a binary thing.  Sounds like MySQL does not support Unicode.  Please tell me this is a joke.

Comment: @tchrist: MySQL 5.5.3 and up support proper UTF-8 via the new "utf8mb4" "character set" ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode.html ). However, the "utf8" "character set" only supports up to 3-byte UTF-8 multibyte characters, reportedly to prevent replication problems between different MySQL versions. "utf8" may change to an alias for "utf8mb4" in a future MySQL release.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491431/remove-4-byte-characters-from-a-utf-8-string) except it is requesting a solution in PHP rather than Java.

Comment: @pvgoddin Which Apache lib is replacing characters with question mark?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We ended up implementing the following method in Java for this problem.
Basicaly replacing the characters with a higher codepoint then the last 3byte UTF-8 char.

The offset calculations are to make sure we stay on the unicode code points.

```
public static final String LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR = "\uFFFF";
public static final String REPLACEMENT_CHAR = "\uFFFD"; 

public static String toValid3ByteUTF8String(String s)  {
    final int length = s.length();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
       final int codepoint = s.codePointAt(offset);

       // do something with the codepoint
       if (codepoint > CharUtils.LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR.codePointAt(0)) {
           b.append(CharUtils.REPLACEMENT_CHAR);
       } else {
           if (Character.isValidCodePoint(codepoint)) {
               b.appendCodePoint(codepoint);
           } else {
               b.append(CharUtils.REPLACEMENT_CHAR);
           }
       }
       offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used this to avoid converting my entire MySQL character set. I don't need the alien character or the poo character in my data.

Comment: Shouldn't `LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR` be of `char` or `int` type? As otherwise `codepoint > CharUtils.LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR` shouldn't be even compiling.

Answer (score 13):

Another simple solution is to use regular expression `[^\u0000-\uFFFF]`. For example in java:

```
text.replaceAll("[^\\u0000-\\uFFFF]", "\uFFFD");
```

Answer (score 2):

5 byte utf-8 sequences begin with a 111110xx-byte and 6 byte utf-8 sequences begin with a 1111110x-byte. Important to note is, that no follow-up bytes of 1-4-byte utf-8 sequences contain bytes that large because follow-up bytes are always of the form 10xxxxxx.

Therefore you can just go through the bytes and every time you see a byte of kind 111110xx then only emit a '?' to the output-stream/array while skipping the next 4 bytes from the input; analogue for the 6-byte-sequences.

Comment: 5 and 6-byte sequences are invalid in UTF-8 anyways - that's not to say that they cannot appear in the source text though.

Comment: if 5 and 6 byte sequences are not legal any way they (should) be less of a problem. my problem is currently with 4byte sequences which are legal yet nog supported by mysql.

Comment: ouch. you changed your question to consider 4-byte-sequences instead of 5/6. now people will think that my answer is false. maybe you could change your question back and create a new question for the 4-byte-case instead? thank you!