# DB2 UTF-8 XML C2 85 to new line conversion

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, db2-luw

We have problem when saving XML data ( UTF-8) encoded to DB2 9.7 LUW in table.

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE DB2ADMIN.TABLE_FOR_XML
(   
  ID           INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  XML_FIELD      XML   NOT NULL
)
```

Problem occurs in some rare examples with rare Unicode characters, we are using java jdbc db2 driver.

For example looking in editor in normal mode not in hex view (Notepad++) this strange A below (after 16.) is represented as NEL in blacks square

Input XML is in UTF-8 encoding and when looked in HEX editor has this values:

```
00000010h: 31 36 2E 20 C2 85 42                            ; 16. Â…B
```

After inserting in DB2 I presume that some kind of conversion occurs because when selecting data back this same character are now

```
00000010h: 31 36 2E 20 0D 0A 42                            ; 16. ..B
```

C2 85 is transformed into 0D 0A that is new line.

One another thing I noticed that although when saving XML into table header content was starting with
    `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">`

but after fetching xml from db2 content was starting with

`<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16">`

Is there way to force db2 to store XML in UTF-8 without conversions ? Fetching with XMLSERIALIZE didn't help

SELECT XML_FIELD AS CONTENT1, XMLSERIALIZE(XML_FIELD  as cLOB(1M))  AS CONTENT2 from DB2ADMIN.TABLE_FOR_XML

IN content2 there is no XML header but stile newLine is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is standard for XML 1.1 processors. [XML 1.1 s2.11](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-line-ends):

> the XML processor must behave as if it normalized all line breaks in external parsed entities (including the document entity) on input, before parsing, by translating [the single character #x85] to a single #xA character

Line ending type is one of the many details of a document that will be lost over a parse-and-serialise cycle (eg attribute order, whitespace in tags, numeric character references...).

It's slightly surprising that DB2's XML fields are using XML 1.1 since not much uses that revision of XML, but not super-surprising in that support for NEL (ancient, useless mainframe line ending character) is something only IBM ever wanted.

> Is there way to force db2 to store XML in UTF-8 without conversions ?

Use a BLOB?

If you need both native-XML-field functionality *and* to retain the exact original serialised form of a document then you'll need two columns.

(Are you *sure* you need to retain NEL line endings? Nobody usually cares about line endings, and these are pretty bogus.)

Comment: No I cloudnt care less for that NEL line ending they are product of error in some input XML, how can I clean XML in Java from this C2 85?

Comment: `xmlString = xmlString.replace("\u0085", "\r\n");` would do. The newline NEL character stems from the EBCDIC encoding, which still is used on some IBM mainframes like AS/400. `\u0085` is in UTF-8 encoded as those two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't generally need non readable characters, before saving XML string to Db2 I decided to implement clean string from x'c285 (code point 133) and 4 byte UTF-8 characters just for the case:

Found similar example([How to replace/remove 4(+)-byte characters from a UTF-8 string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260836/replace-4byte-utf-8-characters/16581577#16581577)) and adjusted it.

```
public static final String LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR = "\uFFFF";
public static final String REPLACEMENT_CHAR = "\uFFFD"; 

public static String toValid3ByteUTF8String(String line)  {
    final int length = line.length();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int offset = 0; offset < length; ) {
       final int codepoint = line.codePointAt(offset);

       // do something with the codepoint
       if (codepoint > LAST_3_BYTE_UTF_CHAR.codePointAt(0)) { //4-byte UTF replace
           b.append(REPLACEMENT_CHAR);
       } else if( codepoint == 133){ //NEL or x'c285 
           b.append(REPLACEMENT_CHAR);
       } else {
           if (Character.isValidCodePoint(codepoint)) {
               b.appendCodePoint(codepoint);
           } else {
               b.append(REPLACEMENT_CHAR);
           }
       }
       offset += Character.charCount(codepoint);
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```