# How to remove non-utf8 chars from a string in javascript/angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can remove non-utf8 chars, like certain emojis, from a string using javascript/angular? The string is coming from a text input and needs to be sanitized because our database currently only handles utf8-chars.

Comment: What's a none utf8 char, seen as utf8 can represent every single glyth known to man.. Here are some uf8-8 emojo's.. 

Comment: Are you using utf8 type in MySQL? If so, you can switch to utf8mb4.

Comment: Explained here for PHP, you should be able to port to JS easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491431/how-to-replace-remove-4-byte-characters-from-a-utf-8-string-in-php

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't think this is a duplicate, since the question is about emojis, and they are not "invalid characters". But the title is def incorrect. Anyway, here's the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/77pxLzny/