# PHP - Convert to UTF-8 / Multilingual European Subset-1

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

Hi there fellow php developers!

In PHP I need to convert from (plain?) UTF-8 to the following format:

- Encoding according to Unicode Transformation Format-8 (UTF-8, described in ISO / IEC 10646-1 / UTF-8);
- Repertoire (limitation) according to the Multilingual European Subset-1 (MES-1, described in standard CWA 13873: 2000);

  1. What is this "Multilingual European Subset-1" ? Is it a difficult way of saying "latin1" / "8859-1" ?
  2. I cannot find PHP documentation on the "Multilingual European Subset-1". Is this "repertoire" available in PHP?

I am aware of the icon_v method (as described here: [Convert utf8-characters to iso-88591 and back in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374425/convert-utf8-characters-to-iso-88591-and-back-in-php)), but apparently this function doesn't cover the MES-1 repertoire

Comment: Just remove not allowed chars from UTF-8 by negate allowed chars: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24672780/1194525

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try to catch the allowed MES-1 chars according to the table in the pdf (par. 4.1 in http://www.evertype.com/standards/iso10646/pdf/cwa13873.pdf):

Plane 00
Rows Positions (Cells)
00 20–7E A0–FF
01 00–13 16–2B 2E–4D 50–7E
02 C7 D8–DB DD
20 15 18–19 1C–1D AC
21 22 26 5B–5E 90–93
26 6A

Any suggestion on how to interpret this? Is there a conversion table from non-MES-1-chars to ascii available which I can use? (I cannot find this)